# Why do home-grown fruits tend to taste better than mass-produced consumer fruits?

Tags: fruit, taste

It is often heard that home-grown fruits and veggies are a lot tastier than the produce found in the supermarket. Although this question may contain a skeptics element in it, it is so often heard there must be at least some biological ground behind it.

Comment: Your whole question is built on a supposition that hardly anyone can truly prove.  Even if you narrowed this down to an objective measure of taste under "organic" versus "non-organic" techniques, it's still driven by opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an unsupported presupposition.

Comment: I must say that home grown stuff (fruit, veggies) *always* taste better (bar the stuff is not overripe and the likes).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Your post might have better to be reformulated to something along the lines of: "it is common knowledge (hope you'll agree) that home grown stuff are better than industrial ones. Why is that? Intuitively, I would think that biotechnology should allow to make fruits that are much more tasty than what a random individual can do in its garden."

Answer (score 3):

"Industrial" fruits and vegetables are not grown as much for flavor as for convenience, pest resistance, appearance, resistance to peel problems, resistance to bruising, etc. etc. Profitability is the main consideration.

There are many varieties of apple grown in orchards that taste *wonderful* (better than my grandmother's gnarly green apples) but don't hold up to shipping and storage well.

Finally, please don't get your information from fantasy tales. There are so many good sites for attaining information.